# Email input form validation showing off the window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for an email input using bootstrap:

```
<form role="form" onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} id = "email-form">
    <div class = "form-group">
        <input type = "email" class = "form-control" id = "email" placeholder = "type e-mail, press enter"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Unfortunately, the error messages for incorrect e-mails are showing off the window here, even when I've scrolled all the way down. Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this? Thanks!

[image: Bottom of the window]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a margin to the bottom of the input? This should give some extra room to show the error message.